# What is the difference in these methods of copying an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to duplicate an array.  Typically, I would just do something like this.

```
int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3};
int[] a2 = a1
```

Recently however, I saw my professor do it this way:

```
int[] ar1 = {1, 2, 3};
int[] ar2 = Arrays.copyOf(ar1);
```

Is there an advantage between doing it one way over the other?  What is the main difference?

Comment: It is fairly easy to test it yourself. I would guess the down vote comes from that. You can use [Arrays.copyof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)) as a reference for your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, both arrays point to the same object. So modifying one will modify the other as well.

```
int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3};
int[] a2 = a1
a1[0] = 15;
System.out.println(a2[0]); //15
```

In the second case, a true copy is created, so modifying one will not affect the other.

```
int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3};
int[] a2 = Arrays.copyOf(a1, 3);
a1[0] = 15;
System.out.println(a2[0]); //1
```

If you want more information about the details of copying in Java, see the second answer to [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)

Comment: @OmarN The second answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java provides a lot more detail about copying in Java if you're interested :)

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree  with @tixpoi's post, but I think this is the right place to add, that the first example of yours is called **shallow copy** and the "true copy" is called **deep copy**.

Comment: Thank you for the info!  I am new to Java and did not know.